# Getting all checkboxes, radio buttons, ratings from an expandable list view: android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an expandable list view that houses a short survey (3-4 fields for a user to insert data about) per record that we have.  Then we have a button that they can hit to submit the data to our server.  When they hit the button I need it to grab all the data in the surveys and send it to our site.  I have the sending portion of it figured out; what I'm struggling with is grabbing all the data from the survey.

I've looked through many of the related posts/google results and attempted to implement and adapt their solution for listviews to expandedlistviews but I have not been able to get any of them working.  I've spent quite a few hours trying to get some workable solution but alas, I cannot figure it out.

I think part of my problem is I'm not exactly certain how children views come into play for expandable list views.  In any event below is my code in hopes that someone smarter than me can help me solve this problem.

So I have my ExpandableListView fragment_survey.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="edu.ucr.aum.fragments.SurveyFragment$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_survey_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/rowPaddingMedium"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rowPaddingMedium"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResponseCode"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_survey_list"
        android:text="Response Code: "/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit Survey"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvResponseCode"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmitSurvey" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my row xml list_view_survey_row.xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSurveyTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/surveyTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSurveyShared"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/surveyShared"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSurveyTitle"
        />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioShared"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSurveyShared">

    <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonYes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:focusable="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonNo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:focusable="true"/>

    </RadioGroup>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSurveyReason"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/surveyReason"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioShared" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSurveyRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/surveyRating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSurveyReason" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxInterest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/surveyInterestPositive"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSurveyRating"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxPrivacy"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/surveyShareLevelPositive"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxInterest"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxPrivacy"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF00FF00"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar" />
```

Then I have a fragment (fragment_survey.java) which adds an onclicklistener to the button (btnSubmitSurvey) in the fragment_survey.xml file.  That onClickListener() function calls two methods (one to get the data and one to send that data).

```
    this.buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getData(v);submitSurvey();
        }
    });


public void getData(View view) {
//get data here
}

public void submitSurvey() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    String url;
    if(Singletons.Debug.debug) {
        url = "url for postback";
    } else {
        url = "url for postback";
    }

    NetworkAsyncTask nat = new NetworkAsyncTask();
    try {
        String response = nat.execute(url).get();
        //Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);
    } catch(ExecutionException e) {

    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this via a horrific hack-job, but it works. I added a button for each row that will allow the user to "save" the row.  When they save the row then the data is saved to my data structure.  Unfortunately to get this working properly I had to create a custom OnClickListener which takes the view as an argument and from there I can scrape the elements from the view.

It's not an elegant or good solution; but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a data structure like an array to store the survey data, I would index it by group and/or child position, whatever makes sense for the data. Then you should add listeners for each question input, when a question is answered yes, add into that data structure the answer at the appropriate location. Then when you press the submit button it can iterate over that data structure, prompt for unanswered questions or fill out default values, gather it all together and then submit.

Basically there's no easy/built in way to access the individual rows of your dynamic/reusable rows that I have been able to find. When the context of which row is important I've found the best way is to have my own data structure that uses the group/child position to find which button is being pressed since every row has a button with the same id. I also store the group position/index in the button using setHint on creation so that in the context of the listener i can determine the position.